# Change CSS class of 1st sibling using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a javascript for a navigation menu.
The `<a class="HeaderCategoryLink" href="/aquarien">Aquarien</a>` Element should have the CSS class "header-menu-sublist-hover" while the user hovers over the `<div onmouseover="SublistMouseenter()" class="sublist first-level"></div>`.
I tried to solve this by selecting the sibling with the index 0 of the div that triggers the javascript and then adding the class to it.
The class is not added to the link when I debug it.

HTML:

```
<ul>    
    <li> <!--first navigation option-->        
        <a class="HeaderCategoryLink" href="/aquarien">Aquarien</a>
        <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
        <div onmouseenter="SublistMouseenter()" class="sublist first-level">
            <ul class="sublistbox">
                <li>
                    <a href="/sets">Sets</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nano">Nano</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/kombinationen">Kombinationen</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/becken">Becken</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li> 
    <li> <!--second navigation option-->      
        <a class="HeaderCategoryLink" href="/aquarien">Aquarien</a>
        <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
        <div onmouseenter="SublistMouseenter()" class="sublist first-level">
            <ul class="sublistbox">
                <li>
                    <a href="/sets">Sets</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nano">Nano</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/kombinationen">Kombinationen</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/becken">Becken</a>
                    <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascipt:

```
function SublistMouseenter()
{
    var CategoryLink = $(this).parentElement.eq(0);
    CategoryLink.addClass('header-menu-sublist-hover');
    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        CategoryLink.removeClass('header-menu-sublist-hover');
    });
};
```

Comment: You can use pseudo class `:hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the anchor tag an id and call this function on the div to change the anchors classname on mouseover.

http://jsfiddle.net/58898k9z/17/

```
function SublistMouseenter(myAnchorsID) {
    if (document.getElementById(myAnchorsID).className == "HeaderCategoryLink") {
        document.getElementById(myAnchorsID).className = "header-menu-sublist-hover";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(myAnchorsID).className = "HeaderCategoryLink";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a list-item of the unordered list of my navigaion. If I do it like this I would have to give every link a unique ID. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Only the elements that change classnames will need an id, but you can use the same function if it's edited slightly. Can you explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: I edited the HTML, It is a menu with categories, these have subcategories  which also have subcategories.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to edit the answer, you may also want a onmouseout event for the list-item so nothing gets stuck the wrong color when it's not hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things are wrong with your code. parentElement is not a jQuery function, parent() is. Also eq(0) will not select the first child. You could use find() instead.

With that in mind, the first line of your function would look more like this:

```
var CategoryLink = $(this).parent().first();
```

or

```
var CategoryLink = $(this).parent().find('a.HeaderCategoryLink');)
```

Answer (score 0):

hi though answer is accepted but you can make this happen with only css then why you need to write javascript code and here is the example of that you just need to apply only this css lines

```css
li .HeaderCategoryLink + .first-level{
    display : none;
}

li .HeaderCategoryLink:hover + .first-level{
    display : block;
}
```

and here is the demo working code for this you can check out here

**[Checkout](https://jsfiddle.net/2yupubcr/)**

Comment: @Orlando hey you can check out here answer with only css code